# Accessing to elements of an array in Row object format and concatenate them- pySpark

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a `pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame`, where one of the columns has an array of `Row` objects:

```
    +------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    |column                                                                          |
    +------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    |[Row(arrival='2019-12-25 19:55', departure='2019-12-25 18:22'),                                 |
    |  Row(arrival='2019-12-26 14:56', departure='2019-12-26 08:52')]                                |
    +------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Not all the rows in the column have the same quantity of elements (in this case, we have 2 but we could have more).

What I am trying to do is to generate a concatenation of the **hours** of each date, to have something like this:

```
18:22_19:55_08:52_14:56
```

This means, the **departure** time of the first element, concatenated with the **arrival** time of the first element, concatenated again with the **departure** time of the second element and once again with the **arrival** time of the second element.

Is there a simple way to do so using `pyspark`?

Answer (score 2):

Assume the column name is `col1` which is an array of structs:

```
df.printSchema()                                                                                                    
root
 |-- col1: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- arrival: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- departure: string (nullable = true)
```

**Method-1: for spark 2.4+, use [array_join](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/sql/index.html#array_join) + [transform](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/sql/index.html#transform)**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

df.withColumn('new_list', expr("""
    array_join(
        transform(col1, x -> concat(right(x.departure,5), '_', right(x.arrival,5)))
      , '_'
    )
  """) 
).show(truncate=False)

+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
|col1                                                                        |new_list               |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
|[[2019-12-25 19:55, 2019-12-25 18:22], [2019-12-26 14:56, 2019-12-26 08:52]]|18:22_19:55_08:52_14:56|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
```

**Method-2: Use udf:**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

def arrays_join(arr):
    return '_'.join('{}_{}'.format(x.departure[-5:], x.arrival[-5:]) for x in arr) if isinstance(arr, list) else arr    

udf_array_join = udf(arrays_join, StringType())

df.select(udf_array_join('col1')).show(truncate=False)
```

**Method-3: use posexplode + groupby + collect_list:**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import monotonically_increasing_id, posexplode, regexp_replace, expr

(df.withColumn('id', monotonically_increasing_id()) 
    .select('*', posexplode('col1').alias('pos', 'col2')) 
    .select('id', 'pos', 'col2.*') 
    .selectExpr('id', "concat(pos, '+', right(departure,5), '_', right(arrival,5)) as dt") 
    .groupby('id') 
    .agg(expr("concat_ws('_', sort_array(collect_list(dt))) as new_list")) 
    .select(regexp_replace('new_list', r'(?:^|(?<=_))\d+\+', '').alias('new_list')) 
    .show(truncate=False))
```

**Method-4: use string operations:**

for this particular problem only, convert the array into string and then do a bunch of string operations (split + concat_ws + regexp_replace + trim) to get desired sub-strings:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace, concat_ws, split, col

(df.select(
    regexp_replace(
        concat_ws('_', split(col('col1').astype('string'), r'[^0-9 :-]+'))
      , r'[_ ]+\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d '
      , '_'
    ).alias('new_list')
).selectExpr('trim(both "_" from new_list) as new_list') 
.show(truncate=False))
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer! Unfortunately I have Spark 2.3.1.Isn't there other way?

Comment: for older version, you might have to use udf.

Comment: BTW, you can also use explode + concat + groupby + collect_list, but also need to add a unique id. if the order of the list is important, then will be a little more extra work. it will not be an very efficient way anyway.

Comment: for this particular problem, the task can also be handled by some string manipulations, see the updated method-4.