# how to extract a list of value for map in array?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, schema

in my dataframe i have this schema:

```
root
 |-- data: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: map (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- key: integer
 |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = false)
```

with for example this values:

```
"DATA":[{"message":"A", "AlternateMessage":"B"},{"message":"C", "AlternateMessage":"D"},{"message":"E", "AlternateMessage":"F"}]
```

i need:

```
MESSAGE="A,C,E"
ALTERNEATE_MESSAGE="B,D,F"
```

i use

```
df=sf.withColumn("message",F.concat_ws(df.data.message))
```

but i have error.

some helps?
thanks

Comment: if you can use spark 2.4+, then use transform + array_join, similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59374628: